# Scroll Bar not appearing along with JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

okay, so I recently made a java console application that brute forced your password so now I was working on a similar app but with a gui.
So I have all the code and its running but for some reason, a scroll bar I added to a textArea is not appearing and when I run the program iI get neither the scroll bar nor the text area. 
Please tell me where I am going wrong and help me solve this issue.

```
package swinggui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BruteForce {
    static JFrame frameObject;
    static JPanel panelObject;

JLabel lblPassword;
JTextField txtPassword;
JTextArea txtStatus;
JScrollPane scrollbar;

JButton btn;

BruteForce() {
    panelObject = new JPanel();
    frameObject.getContentPane().add(panelObject);
    panelObject.setLayout(null);

    txtStatus = new JTextArea("Status: ");
    txtStatus.setBounds(10,95,260,160);
    panelObject.add(txtStatus);

    lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
    txtPassword = new JTextField();

    Font dialog = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14);

    lblPassword.setBounds(10,10,100,30);
    lblPassword.setFont(dialog);
    panelObject.add(lblPassword);

    txtPassword.setBounds(80,10,190,30);
    panelObject.add(txtPassword);

    scrollbar = new JScrollPane(txtStatus);
    panelObject.add(scrollbar);

    btn = new JButton("Test Password Strength");
    btn.setBounds(10,50,260,30);
    panelObject.add(btn);

    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int password = Integer.parseInt(txtPassword.getText());

            int guess_password = 0;
            while(guess_password != password) {
                txtStatus.append("\n [+] Password Attempt: " + guess_password);
                guess_password = guess_password + 1;
            }
            if(guess_password == password) {
                txtStatus.append("\n \n [-] Password Found: " + guess_password);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    frameObject = new JFrame("Brute Force Tool");
    frameObject.setVisible(true);
    frameObject.setSize(300,300);
    frameObject.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BruteForce gui = new BruteForce();
}

}
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong and correct my code.
Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @RoyalSlayer YT First thing do not use `null` layout  use layout manager' s. Second thing you have don't need to add text area into panel, add the text area into `ScrollPane` then `setbounds` to `ScrollPane` not to text area.

Answer (score 0):

First of all an important hint: Don't use null layout. Please learn all standard [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and use them to fill your UI. Also you can use some third-party layout manager like MigLayout or FormLayout (use Google to find them). These managers are often better then the standard.

Why is it better than null-layout? because Java-UI is cross-platform and some components can require different size on different OSs. The same can occur when the user uses some OS-features (like font scaling). Also layout manager defines the resize behavoir (what should happen when user changes the size of the window).

And here is the corrected version of your code (without layout manager change).

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class BruteForce {
    static JFrame frameObject;

    JPanel panelObject;

    JLabel lblPassword;

    JTextField txtPassword;

    JTextArea txtStatus;

    JScrollPane scrollbar;

    JButton btn;

    BruteForce() {
        panelObject = new JPanel();
        frameObject.getContentPane().add(panelObject);
        panelObject.setLayout(null);

        txtStatus = new JTextArea("Status: ");
        // set bounds not required here. it's required for scrollbar
        // txtStatus.setBounds(10,95,260,160);
        panelObject.add(txtStatus);

        lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
        txtPassword = new JTextField();

        Font dialog = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14);

        lblPassword.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);
        lblPassword.setFont(dialog);
        panelObject.add(lblPassword);

        txtPassword.setBounds(80, 10, 190, 30);
        panelObject.add(txtPassword);

        scrollbar = new JScrollPane(txtStatus);
        // set the scroll bar bounds
        scrollbar.setBounds(10, 95, 260, 160);
        panelObject.add(scrollbar);

        btn = new JButton("Test Password Strength");
        btn.setBounds(10, 50, 260, 30);
        panelObject.add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int password = Integer.parseInt(txtPassword.getText());

                int guess_password = 0;
                while (guess_password != password) {
                    txtStatus.append("\n [+] Password Attempt: " + guess_password);
                    guess_password = guess_password + 1;
                }
                if (guess_password == password) {
                    txtStatus.append("\n \n [-] Password Found: " + guess_password);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        frameObject = new JFrame("Brute Force Tool");
        BruteForce gui = new BruteForce();
        frameObject.add(gui.panelObject); // don't forget to place your panel in the window
        frameObject.setSize(300, 300);
        frameObject.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameObject.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center location for window
        frameObject.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that you don't need an application to figure out that if you supply an integer password value (like 55673) and if you iterate through each value one at a time in a loop that it will take the password number of attempts (55673 iterations) to get to that password. We'll just chalk it up as an example. :/

In my opinion there are a number of issues with your particular project that needs some attention:

For a little easier coding, set the **BruteForce** Class so that it **extends JFrame**: `public class BruteForce extends javax.swing.JFrame {`. You won't need the static JFrame variable (**frameObject**) and it cleans things up somewhat.

Take out all that code related to the JFrame out of the **main()** method. Do your JFrame setup within a *initialization* method instead. In my opinion, I think your **main()** method would be better if you have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

   /* Create and display the form */
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           new BruteForce().setVisible(true);
       }
   });
}
```

And your initialization method might look like this:

```
private void initializeComponents() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Brute Force Tool");
    setResizable(false);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);


    // Size the Form
    // Slightly different from original size since
    // form has been made non-resizable. Makes the
    // form more uniformed.
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(285, 325));
    setSize(getPreferredSize());

    // Center Form to screen. Should always be after sizing
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); 

    panelObject = new JPanel();
    panelObject.setLayout(null);

    // Password Box Label
    Font dialog = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
    lblPassword.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);
    lblPassword.setFont(dialog);
    panelObject.add(lblPassword);

    // Password Entry Text Field
    txtPassword = new JTextField();
    txtPassword.setBounds(80, 10, 190, 30);
    panelObject.add(txtPassword);

    // Text Area with Scroll Pane to display 
    // Brute Force process.
    txtStatus = new JTextArea("Status: ");
    scrollbar = new JScrollPane(txtStatus);
    scrollbar.setBounds(10, 125, 260, 160);
    panelObject.add(scrollbar);

    // Button to start Brute Force Process
    btn = new JButton("Test Password Strength");
    btn.setBounds(10, 50, 260, 30);
    panelObject.add(btn);

    // Display Progress CheckBox
    chkUpdateStatus = new JCheckBox("Display Progress");
    chkUpdateStatus.setBounds(10, 85, 150, 30);
    panelObject.add(chkUpdateStatus);

    // Scroll Progress CheckBox
    chkScrollUpdate = new JCheckBox("Scroll Progress");
    chkScrollUpdate.setBounds(160, 85, 150, 30);
    panelObject.add(chkScrollUpdate);

    // Add filled JPanel to JFrame
    panelObject.setBounds(this.getBounds());
    getContentPane().add(panelObject);


    // Add Button Action Listener
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!workThreadIsRunning) { 
                // Clear the TextArea
                txtStatus.setText(null);
                new Thread(workThread).start(); 
            }
            if (btn.getText().equals("Cancel Test")) {
                shutDownThread = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Which then means that your class constructor (**BruteForce()**) simply contains:

```
public BruteForce() {
    initializeComponents();
}
```

If you are not going to use **JFrame#pack()** so that JFrame is automatically sized according to all its contents at or above their preferred sizes then the **setSize()** method to size the JFrame on its own won't help you much. You will also need to use the **setPreferredSize()** method as well in this case.

When creating your form, you want to add JTextArea **into** the JScrollPane, not the JPanel. It will then be the JScrollPane you add into the JPanel.

The **setBounds()** for JTextArea is not required since it will be filling the entire JScrollPane container. With the **null** layout you are using it will be the JScrollPane which will need the **setBounds()** supplied.

Since you are using the **Null** layout and your application window is
indeed small enough, and you've set boundries for all the components, you should also ensure that the JFrame window can not be resized (`setResizable(false);`) since the form would look ridiculous if it was. I'm sure you've been preached to enough to know why **Null** Layout is not necessarily a good choice. But if that isn't enough for you then Google this: [Why is null layout in Swing frowned upon?](https://www.google.ca/search?ei=qBBWW4ziFMms0gKKxoKwAg&q=Why+is+null+layout+in+Swing+frowned+upon%3F&oq=Why+is+null+layout+in+Swing+frowned+upon%3F&gs_l=psy-ab.3...513022.530225.0.531781.17.13.0.0.0.0.215.1070.11j1j1.13.0....0...1c.1j2.64.psy-ab..6.0.0....0.JJj-7SOmof4). It does however have its place in the world especially when utilizing multiple layouts.

> **On a side note:**

Understandably, when processing something like this it is usually nice to see the progress of that process while it is being carried out. The sad reality is that speed is **seriously** hampered when trying to do so.

To effectively update the JTextArea by appending a line to it indicating the brute force attempt (iteration) processed you need to use a new thread to carry out that updating. This of course means that the processing (attempts) are carried out in a separate Thread and not done within the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which will not update the JTextArea until all the processing is complete (which is what you are doing in your code). By placing the processing code within its own thread that updates the JTextArea immediatly is really the only viable option but it does takes time to write that update to the JTextArea...considerable time as a matter of fact.

As an example if you run the supplied runnable code (your code modified) below and supply a password of **222222**, on my system it will take about **2147** milliseconds (around 2 seconds) to complete the task. If you were to comment out the **textStatus.append(...)** within the loop you would find that it only takes about **6** milliseconds (around 0.006 seconds) to complete the task. This is a very significant difference in processing time and if you're doing something like **Brute Force** you want every scrap of speed you can get. If you want the JTextArea to automatically scroll so as to display each update within the view port then speed is hampered **much much** more.

Progress display should be made optional with the use of Check Boxes which I did implement in the sample runnable code below and because the brute force processing is done within its own thread rather than the EDT, any changes to the Check Boxes takes immediate affect. The button also has a more toggle effect so that brute force processing can be canceled.

Here's the full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class BruteForce extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JPanel panelObject;
    JLabel lblPassword;
    JTextField txtPassword;
    JTextArea txtStatus;
    JScrollPane scrollbar;
    JButton btn;
    JCheckBox chkUpdateStatus;
    JCheckBox chkScrollUpdate;
    Runnable workThread;
    boolean workThreadIsRunning = false;
    volatile boolean shutDownThread = false;

    public BruteForce() {
        initializeComponents();

        workThread = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                workThreadIsRunning = true;
                int password = Integer.parseInt(txtPassword.getText());
                btn.setText("Cancel Test");
                int guess_password = 0;
                while (guess_password != password & !shutDownThread) {
                    if (chkUpdateStatus.isSelected()) {
                        txtStatus.append("\n [+] Password Attempt: " + String.valueOf(guess_password + 1));
                        if (chkScrollUpdate.isSelected()) {
                            // Update The JTextArea to show immediate processing.
                            // (Slows down processing considerably)
                            txtStatus.setCaretPosition(txtStatus.getText().length() - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    guess_password++;
                }
                long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                if (guess_password == password) {
                    txtStatus.append("\n \n [-] Password Found: " + guess_password);
                    txtStatus.append("\n [-] It took " + duration + " milliseconds\n     "
                                   + "(just over " + String.valueOf(duration / 1000) + " seconds) "
                                   + "to\n     accomplish.");
                    txtStatus.setCaretPosition(txtStatus.getText().length() - 1);
                }
                workThreadIsRunning = false;
                btn.setText("Test Password Strength");
                shutDownThread = false;
            }
        };
    }

    private void initializeComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Brute Force Tool");
        setResizable(false);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);


        // Size the Form
        // Slightly different from original size since
        // form has been made non-resizable. Makes the
        // form more uniformed.
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(285, 325));
        setSize(getPreferredSize());

        // Center Form to screen. Should always be after sizing
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 

        panelObject = new JPanel();
        panelObject.setLayout(null);

        // Password Box Label
        Font dialog = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
        lblPassword.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);
        lblPassword.setFont(dialog);
        panelObject.add(lblPassword);

        // Password Entry Text Field
        txtPassword = new JTextField();
        txtPassword.setBounds(80, 10, 190, 30);
        panelObject.add(txtPassword);

        // Text Area with Scroll Pane to display 
        // Brute Force process.
        txtStatus = new JTextArea("Status: ");
        scrollbar = new JScrollPane(txtStatus);
        scrollbar.setBounds(10, 125, 260, 160);
        panelObject.add(scrollbar);

        // Button to start Brute Force Process
        btn = new JButton("Test Password Strength");
        btn.setBounds(10, 50, 260, 30);
        panelObject.add(btn);

        // Display Progress CheckBox
        chkUpdateStatus = new JCheckBox("Display Progress");
        chkUpdateStatus.setBounds(10, 85, 150, 30);
        panelObject.add(chkUpdateStatus);

        // Scroll Progress CheckBox
        chkScrollUpdate = new JCheckBox("Scroll Progress");
        chkScrollUpdate.setBounds(160, 85, 150, 30);
        panelObject.add(chkScrollUpdate);

        // Add filled JPanel to JFrame
        panelObject.setBounds(this.getBounds());
        getContentPane().add(panelObject);


        // Add Button Action Listener
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!workThreadIsRunning) { 
                    // Clear the TextArea
                    txtStatus.setText(null);
                    new Thread(workThread).start(); 
                }
                if (btn.getText().equals("Cancel Test")) {
                    shutDownThread = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new BruteForce().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```